# Phishing from iOS Apps: Possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, uiwebview, social-networking

I was just trying out this new app I downloaded today and that usual social network login from in-app WebViews made me question something...

Is it possible that some apps that require Twitter/FB/Google login from in-App WebViews (not Safari or their own apps like FB) somehow record the data we write in these WebViews before sending the request over to the site like in a common phishing scam?

For example, I know that Twitter login using oAuth catches the PIN number from the div and uses it against the API and etc. So, maybe the same could happen with Text Fields, right? No?

Anyway, it's just a silly question but I thought I'd ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, phishing via a UIWebView is possible, by [injecting JavaScript into it](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview). This may be part of why Facebook's SDK now opens the Safari app instead of as a lightbox within the app.

Answer (score 0):

Before any application gets published in Apple Application Store the it is reviewed by Apple for malicious intentions etc. So we can say the applications that is downloaded from official Apple Store are relatively secure. Of course there can be some applications that may have unnoticed security issues but phishing is fairly easy to detect by professionals. I don't know for sure but I guess they check if application using encryption for authentication and if app directly logs in Twitter/FB/Google or makes MITM.

Comment: I'm not sure Apple's review process would catch this sort of thing

Answer (score -1):

Where ever javascript engine being used, phishing is possible there (unless input boxes massages input).

Comment: "input boxes massages input"?